# Incorrect string value: '\xCC_a' for column

Tags: php, mysql

Error Received:

> Error Number: 1366
>
> Incorrect string value: '\xCC_a' for column
>   'last_name' at row 1
>
> UPDATE `phppos_people` SET `first_name` = 'Juan Gordon', `last_name` =
>   'Garc�_a', `email` = 'EMAIL@email.com', `phone_number` = '',
>   `address_1` = '', `address_2` = '', `city` = '', `state` = '', `zip` =
>   '', `country` = '', `comments` = '' WHERE `person_id` = 
>   '238'
>
> Filename:
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/PHP-Point-Of-Sale/models/person.php
>
> Line
>   Number: 85

Code:

```
//Skip first row
fgetcsv($handle);
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) 
{
    $person_data = array(
    'first_name'=>$data[0],
    'last_name'=>$data[1],
    'email'=>$data[2],
    'phone_number'=>$data[3],
    'address_1'=>$data[4],
    'address_2'=>$data[5],
    'city'=>$data[6],
    'state'=>$data[7],
    'zip'=>$data[8],
    'country'=>$data[9],
    'comments'=>$data[10]
    );

    $customer_data=array(
    'account_number'=>$data[11]=='' ? null:$data[11],
    'taxable'=>$data[12]=='' ? 0:1,
    'company_name' => $data[13],
    );
    if($this->Customer->exists($data[14]))
    {
        $this->Customer->save($person_data,$customer_data,$data[14]);
    }
    else if(!$this->Customer->save($person_data,$customer_data))
    {   
        echo json_encode( array('success'=>false,'message'=>lang('customers_duplicate_account_id')));
        return;
    }
}
```

Database column uses utf8_unicode_ci encoding

I tried using utf8_encode, but that didn't work

Comment: See [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/a/279279).

Comment: I read this and it seems I am doing all of these, but I think the problem is something to do with fgetcsv

Comment: Please show the code that connects to the database and then executes the `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: I am using CodeIgniter. $db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with your encode. To solve that you should invoke the function utf8_encode on the value before store, like that.

```
$person_data = array(
'first_name' => $data[0],
'last_name'  => utf8_encode($data[1]),
...
```

I use CodeIgniter also, and the database configuration is:

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
```